# java.nio.BufferOverflowException despite buffer.clear()

Tags: java, sockets, memcached, socketchannel

I am implementing a middleware between clients of the `memaslap`benchmark and the `memcached`server. The key size is set to 16Bytes and the value size to 1024Bytes, so the request should never exceed 2048Bytes which is `MAX_PACKET_LENGTH` in the following code fragment:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(MAX_PACKET_LENGTH);

while(running) {
    try {
        buffer.clear();
        socketChannel.read(buffer);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ....
}
```

It is very strange to me why after a certain amount of requests (it is never the same amount) there occurs a BufferOverflow despite I did a `buffer.clear()` before.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What line / method is throwing the exception? `SocketChannel.read()` never tries to read more data than would fit in the buffer, so it will not throw a `BufferOverflowException`. One way I imagine it might happen is if you are modifying the buffer from another thread while `SocketChannel.read()` is being executed.

Comment: @Jesper you were right. There are other threads which are modifying the buffer. Sending a duplicate to the other thread solved the problem. thx